# How to set jinja value as html tag

Tags: python, html, mysql, database, jinja2

I am working on a flask blog app

In this, I am using MySQL and getting the data from aap.py in `posts=posts`

In index.html I am getting the value of post_title, slug, and content.
But what I want is the content, to be inside HTML tags, so I wrote content in HTML tags in Database and retrieve it in the index page, But the HTML tags are not working because it is getting the value from jinja into "". So the HTML tags are not processed!

For e.g

```
content = <h1>Hello</h1><br>  (not a bar just explaining)
pushing content to MySQL database
retrieving content in index.html inside a p tag using jinja variable
But the result is

<p>"<h1>Hello</h1><br>"</p>
```

but the output is

Hello

and I want

## Hello

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using js

a p tag which with id p is already in the HTML document

using js

document.getElementById("p").html = the HTML you want to insert

It worked for me